# Variant options on Shopify

Tags: shopify, product-variations

I've been trying to create variant options which also have prices on a Shopify theme, and represent them by checkboxes. So end user can select multiple options with additional prices. But shopify has limitations on this as far as I noticed.

Let's say the product is 'personal computer' with fixed price £500, and it has options like 'graphic card - £30', 'processor - £40', 'sound card - £15', 'sound card - £30'. As you've noticed there can be multiple options with different prices in addition to the main product price. And as I would like to use checkboxes, users can select min 1 max all of them.

I don't want to use the Shopify app for this but it seems there is no other choice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would prefer to organize it like this.

```
make a personal computer product. it costs 500
make a graphics card product. it costs 30
make a processor product. it costs 40
make a sound card product. it costs 15, 30 or whatever.
```

Now present all four products on a page so the customer can check off one or more of those products. The ones they check off go into the cart.

You get inventory control that way. You can also price each product up to 100 different ways.

You do not need an App to go this route. It works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It rings the bell. My current situation is different than 'having an option as a product' but it might help. I'll give it a try. Thanks.